# Replace tags with new tags with innerHTML to set to id

Tags: javascript, regex, replaceall

I have the following text:

```
Send to <a class="tipo9" id="1">Example Mark</a> and <a class="tipo0" id="3">Testing James</a> a new Document
```

And would like to obtain the following code:

```
Send to <per>1</per> and <per>3</per> a new Document
```

The number between the  tags is the id number.

I have found a very complicated solution like:

```
function convert(f) {
    var str=f;
    str=str.replaceAll('<a class="', '[per]');
    str=str.replaceAll('/a>', '[/per]');
    str=str.replaceAll(/tipo\d/g, '');
    str=str.replaceAll(/['"]+/g, '');
    str=str.replaceAll('"', '');
    str=str.replaceAll(' id=', '');
    str=str.replaceAll(/\s*\>.*?\<\s*/g, "")
    str=str.replaceAll('[per]', '<per>');
    str=str.replaceAll('[/per]', '</per>');
    str=str.trim();
    document.getElementById('testoHTML').value=str;
}
```

but it gives different problems. I know that it should exist another solution with regex but I was not able to obtain a working result.

Hope to find some good solution :)

Comment: Why not put the HTML into a document fragment, and use the DOM instead of string replacement?

Comment: What does Java have to do with this?

Comment: Select the element and use replaceWith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more like a job for [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
var parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString('Send to <a class="tipo9" id="1">Example Mark</a> and <a class="tipo0" id="3">Testing James</a> a new Document', "text/html");
parsed.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(e=>{
  n = document.createElement("pre");
  n.innerHTML  = e.id;
  e.replaceWith(n);
})
var result = parsed.body.innerHTML;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unclear why you would use a regular expression to update HTML when DOM methods are built for it.

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll(".foo > a");
elems.forEach(elem => {
  const updateElem = document.createElement("p");
  updateElem.textContent = elem.id;
  elem.replaceWith(updateElem);
});
```

```html
<div class="foo">Send to <a class="tipo9" id="1">Example Mark</a> and <a class="tipo0" id="3">Testing James</a> a new Document</div>
```

Comment: The input HTML is a string. May you add that transformation to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to point out that **regex is not recommended to be used when you need to access/modify HTML or XML**. More on that in:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

That said, it's possible to use regex to reach that result as follows:

```
find:
<a.+?id="([^"])+".+?/a>

re:
<per>\1</per>
```

Explanation:

- find a '<a'
- consume all letters until 'id="' is found, then consume 'id="'
- save the number of id as the first group by selecting everything until '"' is found
- consume '"' and all the reamining closing '/a>'
- finally, since everything from openning '<a' to closing '/a>' was select, it will be all replaced by '\1', where \1 is the content of the first group

I just wrote plain regex because since you asked for a regex solution. But the correct way to deal with this task is by using DOM